# Need help in echo php

Tags: php

I am trying to show some text by default in values tag.I am trying to echo the $row in form value. But, i am getting notice about undefined variable. Can anybody figure out the error?

```
<?php  
$id=$_GET['id'];
$qry=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageid="$id"', $con);
if(!$qry)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
$row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
}
?>

<div class="block2">
<p><b>Update Article</b></p>
<form action="article_edited.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"     name="form1" id="form1">
<p>Article Id &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:

<label for="image"></label>
<input type="text" name="pageid" id="pageid" value="<?php echo $row['pageid']?>" />
</p>
<label for="image"></label>
<p>Image Path:
<input type="text" name="imgpath" id="imgpath" value="<?php echo $row['imgpath'] ?>" />
</p>
<p>Contents &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:
<label for="cont"></label>
<textarea name="contents" id="contents" cols="50" rows="5" ><?php $row['text']     ?></textarea>
</p>
<p align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

Update #1: This is the tutorial i was following :http://www.vdesignourweb.com/cmsphpsqlb/cms_editarticle.html

Update #2: This is the my Table structure :[image: DB info]

Update #3: I just found that the table has no index. Can this be the problem?

Comment: you might want to move the closing } of your while statement behind the last occurance of your use of $row

Comment: off topic but important: please note that the `mysql_xx()` functions are considered obsolete and not recommended for use. You should consider switching to either the equivalent `mysqli_xx()` funcs or the PDO library. (note that the PHP manual has strongly worded warnings to this effect)

Comment: I am quite new to PHP,I will make changes in code.Thanks @SDC.

Comment: no worries. hope I helped :) Make sure you're learning from a good tutorial that is up-to-date. There's a lot of PHP code on the web that uses out-dated techniques.

Comment: I agree with that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You are only defining `$row` in the while loop. It is not defined outside of the while loop. You need to store the value in an array or something to last once the while loop ends or act during the while loop!

```
    $results = array();

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
        $results [] = $row;
    }

    foreach($results as $row){
        echo $row['pageid'];
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to find the same example for 4 hours.Can you please show  an example?

Comment: `$row` is defined after the loop, but it is `false`. It is being set inside the loop condition.

Comment: @mcrumley. Will mysqli_fetch_array() fix that thing? or its the same.

Answer (score 1):

If its a single record, you can check if there is a record returned from the query and just use

`$row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);`

instead of

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
$row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
}
```

You might also look into `mysql_fetch_row`. I would recommend steering away from mysql_* though, its old and deprecated.

Comment: 3 rows will be returned in this query.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your while loop as follows:

```
$array=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    $array[]=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
}
```

Then, in your textarea, make it say

```
<?php echo $row['text'] //you missed the echo statement ?>
```

Alternatively, instead of `<?php echo //what you want to echo ?>` you can simply use `<?= //what you want to echo here ?>`

Comment: By the way, as per your chosen terminology it looks like your pageid is a unique identifier for your pages table. If that is the case, you don't need to loop through the results, since if you look for a certain id in the table, there will only be one result. `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result)` will suffice.

Comment: Making changes suggested by you removes the undefined variable thing but does not give any output.

Comment: That sounds like the associative keys are not the same as the table columns.

Answer (score 0):

It is getting a single record then you have to use single

```
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
```

Answer (score 0):

The last time the `while` loop executes, `$row` is set to `false` because `mysql_fetch_array($qry)` returns `false` when there are no more rows. After the loop, `$row['pageid']` does not exist because `$row` is no longer an array.

I can't tell you how to fix it because I am not sure what you are trying to do in your loop. Should the HTML code after the loop be printed for each row?

```
<?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)) { ?>
    <div class="block2">
    ...
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

If you only want one result, you should write the query so you only get one result and skip the `while` loop.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
```

Comment: Actually, i am not trying to do anything in my loop. I want to print the values returned by rows[] in text-input boxes.
I have removed the while loop.But,it does not make any changes.

Comment: So now you just have `$row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);`? It sounds like either the database columns do not match what you are using ("pageid", "imgpath", "text") or there are no matching rows. Try putting `var_dump($row);` and see what `mysql_fetch_array` is returning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do  this like that,

```
<?php  
$id=$_GET['id'];
$qry=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageid="$id"', $con);
if(!$qry)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    $rows[]=$row;
}
?>

<div class="block2">
<p><b>Update Article</b></p>
<form action="article_edited.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"     name="form1" id="form1">
<p>Article Id &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:
<?php 
foreach($rows as $row){
?>
<label for="image"></label>
<input type="text" name="pageid" id="pageid" value="<?php echo $row['pageid']?>" />
</p>
<label for="image"></label>
<p>Image Path:
<input type="text" name="imgpath" id="imgpath" value="<?php echo $row['imgpath'] ?>" />
</p>
<p>Contents &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:
<label for="cont"></label>
<textarea name="contents" id="contents" cols="50" rows="5" ><?php $row['text']     ?></textarea>
</p>
<?php }?>
<p align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

i hope it may help you.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: array in C:\wamp\www\xxx\edit_article.php on line 118

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\xxx\edit_article.php on line 118

Comment: if i modify the code like this:
    `$array[]=array();
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $array[]=$rows;
    }`

I am getting undefined index Notice.

Comment: what result you get for $rows

Comment: {$array[]=array();} it should be like above i mentioned {$array[]=$rows;}

Comment: This gives the the Notice: Undefined variable: array in C:\wamp\www\xxx\edit_article.php on line 118 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\xxx\edit_article.php on line 11

Comment: i have updates the code please have a look. And what is the meaning of  this line $array[]=array();.

Comment: why you are try to add this line $array[]=array();

Comment: i was trying to declare the array variable out of loop.

Comment: I am not sure why you try to store blank array out of the loop.I think you should remove that line and use same code.It should work.